# Other Jalapeño beers?

Tags: ingredients, flavor

I recently drank Stone's "Punishment" which was brewed with jalapeños! Having homebrewed with jalapeños from my garden for years I was super excited. Are there other breweries that have started experimenting with spicing their beers this way?

Comment: In the UK there is a long tradition of spicing beer with cinnamon and recently other spices have been tried Modha ales make a cardamom spiced beer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recently had their "Crime" and loved it. Here are some other beers brewed with Jalapenos, but not a whole lot from major breweries like Stone.

#### Rogue - Chipotle Ale

*"smoked jalapeno peppers"*

[image]

#### Twisted Pine - Ghost Face Killah

*"serrano, jalapeno, habanero, fresno, anaheim"* (notoriously hot)
[image]

#### Alaskan - Jalapeno Imperial IPA

[image]

#### Horseheads - Hot-Jala-Heim

*"jalapenos and anaheim"*

[image]

#### No Label - Don Jalapeno

*"this beer is brewed with 60lbs of jalapenos. 30 lbs raw and 30lbs roasted (seeds included)"*

[image]

#### Hot Box - Imperial Smoked Pepper Porter

*"smoked poblano & jalapeno peppers"*

[image]

Comment: BadWolf brewing in Manassas Virginia has a jalapeño IPA.

Comment: If you can find a label online, by all means feel free to post a separate answer :-)

Comment: Country Boy has a jalapeño porter

Comment: Just as a bit of commentary, I have tried Ghost Face Killah on two occasions, and immediately regretted it both times.  Unlike many other chili beers that I have had, this one destroyed my palette almost immediately.  I consider it something of a "dare" beer, or a last beer of the night.

Answer (score 7):

This is not a jalapeno beer, but along the same lines.  Ballast Pointe brewery out of San Diego, CA makes what they call a Habanero  Sculpin IPA.  It is delicious and you can find it all the way over here on the east coast in NC.  It has a very nice kick to it- it's great with a steak or something kind of heavy, but not so great for beer pong as the habanero really does have a bite to it.
[image]

Answer (score 6):

There are many Jalapeno beers out there. Here is a list of the top 50 rated beers brewed with jalapeno ([source](http://www.ratebeer.com/tag/jalapeno/)):

1. Arizona Wilderness American Presidential Stout
2. Indeed / Northbound Hot Box Imperial Smoked Pepper Porter
3. Stone Smoked Porter - Chipotle Peppers
4. Two Henrys Roasted Jalapeño Blueberry Porter
5. Fate (AZ) Chocolate Chili Milk Stout - Jalapeño
6. Trois Dames / Six Point Jalapenos Raspberry Double
7. Alaskan Pilot Series: Jalapeño Imperial IPA
8. Jaipur Jalapeño Ale
9. Tempest Chipotle Spiced Extra Porter
10. 5 Stones Aloha Piña
11. Birdsong Jalapeno Pale
12. Grand River Jubilation Spiced Ale 2008 Retired
13. Country Boy Jalapeno Smoked Porter
14. Angry Chair Byron IPA - Pineapple and Jalapeño
15. COAST Dave Brown
16. Country Boy Jalapeno Smoked Porter XXX
17. Asheville Fire Escape
18. Coronado Señor Saison
19. Urban Artifact Harrow (Orange, Jalapeno)
20. Evil Twin Spicy Nachos Retired
21. Cigar City Strawberry Jalapeño PB&J Double Cream Ale
22. Banger El Heffe
23. Fate (AZ) Jalapeño Cream Ale
24. Wasatch Jalapeño Cream Ale
25. Fairhope Shallow Jalapeño
26. Manayunk Black Eye P. A.
27. Cigar City Jalapeño Peach Pale Ale
28. Barley Browns Hot Blonde
29. Kuhnhenn Jalapeño Lime Mead
30. Cigar City Florida Cracker - Raspberry & Jalapeño
31. Cigar City Jalapeño Red
32. Town Hall Chipotle Wee Heavy
33. Old Ox Kristin’s Temper: Jalapeno Pale Ale
34. Pizza Port Carlsbad Raceway IPA - Roasted Pineapple & Jalapeño
35. Swamp Head Smoke Signal Porter - Chipotle
36. Steam Plant Jalapeno Ale
37. Throwback Spicy Bohemian
38. Waikiki Jalapeño Mouth
39. Breaker Mine Fire Blackberry Jalapeño Ale
40. Seven Bridges Maple Jalapeno Stout
41. Pizza Port Night Rider - Tequila, Jalapeño & Chocolate Retired
42. Golden City Javapeño Stout Retired
43. Ballast Point Smoke Screen Helles - Jalapeño
44. Original Gravity 440 Pepper Smoker
45. No Label Don Jalapeno Ale
46. Horseheads Hot-Jala-Heim
47. Nickel Back Country Gold - Jalapeño
48. Black Forest Jalepeno Pilsener
49. Rogue Chipotle Ale
50. Fort George Spank Stout

Answer (score 3):

Again, not a jalapeno beer, but a great one nonetheless that incorporates similar thinking. RAR Brewing in Cambridge, MD makes a killer beer called Habanero Nectar.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Bent River (from Rock Island/Moline, IL) has a Jalapeno Pepper Ale. They take it with them when they go to most festivals. I assume it's mostly for novelty. 
Tastes kinda like drinking nacho beer (probably make a good beer dip).

It was added on beeradvocate in like 2005, so apparently they've been doing it for a while.

Answer (score 2):

**[Triangle Brewing Company](http://trianglebrewery.com/beers/)** from Durham, NC make their **Habanero Pale Ale**.

I went on a brewery tour here in 2014, exceptionally minimalist brewery, and very generous with the samples! I've got to say, personally, a half pint would be enough but it's 100% worth trying for the experience alone.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Scoville from [Jailbreak](https://jailbreakbrewing.com/) is a great beer. [Beer Advocate](http://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/profile/34426/118519/)

[image: Welcome to Scoville]